# Overriding logic:Beginner

Tags: java, oop, overriding

I have a doubt in overriding.

```
class base{
public void amethod(){}
}
class child extends base{
public void amethod(int i){}}
```

What happens in this case?Are the methods considered 2 different ones?or does it still override?Pls clarify.

Comment: This would be an easy thing to check on your own with the JVM.  Why not do that instead of asking here?  It'll be faster and more definitive.

Comment: Use `@Override` in the child class. Then the compiler will give an error. (The naming convention for classes is capitalise the initial letter.)

Comment: @duffymo - faster? yes!  definitive?  It is debatable that experimentation gives definitive answers.  You need to do the right experiments, and have enough understanding to interpret the results correctly!.  If you want definitive, read a good book, the Oracle tutorials ... or (for the ultimate in "definitiveness") the JLS.

Comment: Sure, do all those things, but asking questions on SO about what the compiler or runtime will do wouldn't be high on my list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not overriding, but [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), and those two are not related to each other.

Take a look at the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

> Overloaded methods are differentiated by the number and the type of
>   the arguments passed into the method. In the code sample, draw(String
>   s) and draw(int i) are distinct and unique methods because they
>   require different argument types.

Answer (score 0):

*Overriding is two methods have same name and same return type,but different arguments and overriding means two methods that have same name,same arguments,same return type but body must be different in both methods*

```
    public void amethod()
    public void amethod(int i)
```

*i think u got the point that this is **overloading** not **overriding** ...*